# Python, gettext: How to get right locale for module- and class-level variables?

Tags: python, gettext

I have some troubles when i use gettext for module- and class-level variables.

First of all, at import time i use my default locale and install it.
After it I get specific locale when I start my project by parsing settings and use `gettext.translation.install` for set right locale. All work well, but in my code all module- and class-level variables stay translated with default locale, not right.

For example I have project like this:

```
├── foo.py
├── i18t
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── run.py
```

`i18t/__init__.py` contains:

```
import gettext
from os import path

SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ('en', 'fr')
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES[0]

locale_path = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'locale'))

TRANSLATIONS = {
    lang: gettext.translation(
        'domain',
        locale_path,
        languages=[lang]
    ) for lang in SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES
}


def install_language(language):
    lang = TRANSLATIONS.get(language)
    if lang is None:
        lang = TRANSLATIONS[DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]
    lang.install()
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from i18n import DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, install_language

install_language(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)
```

`foo.py`:

```
foo = _('Bar')
```

`run.py`:

```
from i18t import install_language
import foo


def main():
    ...
    read config and get right locale
    ...
    install_language(right_locale)
    bar = _('Bazz')
    print(foo.foo)
    print(bar)
```

I execute `run.py` and I get translated `foo.foo` with default locale and `bar` with right locale.
I know that `foo.foo` run `_`(gettext) only once when I import module but I need to get right translated string.
Which better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of this case is desire to use run-time function `gettext` for strings which evaluated only once in import-time. I think it's better not to do this.

But I resolved this problem with using string-like object like in [speaklater package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speaklater) or inherit object [UserSting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) and make your own `gettext` function:

```
from collections import UserString


class RuntimeTranslatedString(UserString):

    def __init__(self, message):
        self._data = message

    @property
    def data(self):
        return _(self._data)


def N_(message):
    return RuntimeTranslatedString(message)
```

In your code you can use it like `_`(gettext):

```
from .i18n import N_

foo = N_('Bar')
```

Don't forget add it to your `extract_message` command. In my `setup.cfg` it looks like:

```
[extract_messages]
output_file = my-package/i18n/locale/translation.pot
keywords = _ N_
```

I'm not sure that this is the good solution but it works.

Comment: I think N_ function should be `return RuntimeTranslatedString(message).data`

Comment: @LeHoaiDuc thank you for your comment, but actually no, it shouldn't be so. If you would follow the link to documentation of `UserString` you will find that it works as normal python's strings by accessing `data` property. So you can use it as usual string without direct access to `.data`.